# Hyperbolic Trig Proofs/Definitions

Tags: calculus

My first post! Hello World!

I was looking back at my notes from Calculus I & II (my how the time has passed!)
I came back across Hyperbolic Trig Functions, sinh, cosh, etc.

I remember being presented the identities, how to use them, derivatives, integrals, etc. I was wondering if anyone could provide me the proof or how these identities are derived, where exactly does e^x come in to play? I've done some searching and haven't come up with anything, so if an answer already exists can you point me in the right direction? No need to solve a problem that has already been solved!

Thank you and I look forward to asking/answering many questions through my Math school journey!

Update (6-22-16): I meant how are the identities obtained? Where does e^x come into play?

Comment: It's up to you to ask a specific Question (if you want a suitable Answer).  Mathematical expressions can be posted here using [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 1):

$\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$

$\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$

by definition.  Most other identities follow from basic calculus.

Comment: Many of the basic identities ( e.g. $\cosh^2 x-\sinh^2 x=1,$ or the formula for $\cosh (x+y)\;)$  follow from the def'ns of \$\sinh $ and $ \cosh$ and from some elementary algebra.